# Error with rvest package

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from the Securities Class Action Filings website across multiple pages (233). My code is the following:

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("xml2")

library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)


i <- 1:233
urls <- paste0("http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page=", i)

get_table <- function(url) {
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="records"]/table') %>%
    html_table()
}

results <- sapply(urls, get_table)
```

The code results in the following error:

> Error in xpath_element() :
>       could not find function "xpath_element"

Any ideas?

I tried by restarting **R**, restarting the computer and updating all the packages.

Comment: `install.packages("selectr")` solved this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled R - not via Anaconda this time - and now the code is working. Sorry for wasting your guys' time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will get you close to what you need.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rvest))


# iterate over the first 10 pages
iter_page <- 1:10
pb <- progress_estimated(length(iter_page))

# define function to scrape the table data from a page
get_table <- function(i) {
  base_url <- "http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page="
  url <-  paste0(base_url, i)
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="records"]/table') %>%
    html_table() %>% 
    .[[1]] %>%
    as_tibble()
}  

# scrape first 10 pages
map_df(iter_page, ~ {
  pb$tick()$print()
  df <- get_table(.x)
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
  df
})
#> # A tibble: 200 x 5
#>                                                       `Filing Name`
#>                                                               <chr>
#>  1                                    Dr. Reddy's Laboratories Ltd.
#>  2                                             PetMed Express, Inc.
#>  3                                                   Top Ships Inc.
#>  4                                                     Sevcon, Inc.
#>  5                                                     XCerra Corp.
#>  6                                               Zillow Group, Inc.
#>  7                                                   ShoreTel, Inc.
#>  8 Teva Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd. : American Depository Shares
#>  9                                                    Depomed, Inc.
#> 10                                        Blue Apron Holdings, Inc.
#> # ... with 190 more rows, and 4 more variables: `Filing Date` <chr>,
#> #   `District Court` <chr>, Exchange <chr>, Ticker <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code but still receive the same error message. After running
`map_df(.)` R starts to scrape (`|====== | 10% ~1 m remaining`) but ends shortly after with the error message `Error in xpath_element(<S4 object of class "Element">) : 
  could not find function "xpath_element" `